# Get the checksum of an open QIODevice

Tags: c++, qt

i need the checksum of a file and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383392/how-to-get-the-sha-1-md5-checksum-of-a-file-with-qt), which works perfectly fine. Now i want to change this function to take a pointer to a `QIODevice` that has been opened before with the following lines:

```
if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
{
    ...
}
```

This is passed to read (`reader.read(&file);`) as device:

```
bool XmlReader::read(QIODevice* device)
{
    QByteArray b = fileChecksum(device);
    ...
}
```

This is my implementation of fileChecksum. It returns a checksum, but i am caught in a loop forever and i am getting an xml parse error. What am i doing wrong here?

```
QByteArray XmlReader::fileChecksum(QIODevice* device)
{
    if (device->isOpen())
    {
        QCryptographicHash hash(QCryptographicHash::Sha256);
        if (hash.addData(device)) {
            return hash.result();
        }

    }
    return QByteArray();
}
```

**EDIT**

right after `QByteArray b = fileChecksum(device);` i do:

```
qDebug() << "Checksum: " << b.toHex();
```

whick keeps printing and printing and printing...

The parse error is: `premature end of document` which is rubbish.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please post exact error text? Also it is not very clear in what loop you are caught, could you please clarify?

Comment: @tobilocker the error is somewhere that in the parts of your code that is not included in this question. You should be aware that the `addData` function most likely reads the whole file and then doesn't "rewind" the cursor, so you might want to do `auto pos = device->pos();QByteArray b = fileChecksum(device);device->seek(pos);`

Comment: @PeterT That did it! Perfect! If you just add those lines as an answer i can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the lines of code that eventually caused the error are not in view I can only speculate about what happened.

The function `fileChecksum` called `hash.addData(device)` which read the [QIODevice until the end](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcryptographichash.html#addData-2) and kept the cursor position there.

Most likely you tried to read from the QIODevice afterwards which would explain the `premature end of documen` message.

As a fast workaround you can just try to reset the position afterwards with

```
auto pos = device->pos();
QByteArray b = fileChecksum(device);
device->seek(pos);
```

But you should only read the data once if you can (to support non random-access QIODevices too). For example you can store the result in a QBuffer and use that as a QIODevice. Like this:

```
bool XmlReader::read(QIODevice* device)
{
    QByteArray contents = device->readAll();
    QBuffer buffer(&contents);
    device = &buffer;//you can also just use &buffer from here on out instead of overwriting the pointer
    QByteArray b = fileChecksum(device);
    device->reset();
    /* ... further reads from device here */
}
```

Comment: Guess confirmed! Thanks.

Comment: You did not test this right? The above won't compile. There are several errors in your suggested solution with the `QBuffer`. `QByteArray contents = device.readAll();` obviously doesn't work since device is a pointer. `QBuffer` constructor takes a pointer to a `QByteArray` so it must be `QBuffer buffer(&contents)`. Also this results in the same parser error `premature end of document`.

Comment: @tobilocker yep, didn't try to compile. Also, when the error still appears you probably read from `device` outside of the `XmlReader::read` function which I did not assume. I guess just make sure that the `QIODevice` that you pass in is a random access device and then then you can just rely on the initial workaround.